# Incompatible types: capture of ? extends ... is not convertible to capture of ? extends

Tags: java, generics

I have a variable in the object:

```
private final Map<Long, ? extends MovieInfoDTO> bElementsToAdd = new HashMap<>();
```

Using the method in the Builder pattern I want to complete this map.

```
public Builder withElementsToAdd(@Nullable final Map<Long, ? extends MovieInfoDTO> elementsToAdd) {
     this.bElementsToAdd.clear();
     if(elementsToAdd != null) {
         this.bElementsToAdd.putAll(elementsToAdd);
     }
     return this;
}
```

However, I receive an error.

```
    putAll
(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Long,? extends capture<? extends com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.movie.MovieInfoDTO>>)
in Map cannot be applied
to
(java.util.Map<java.lang.Long,capture<? extends com.jonki.popcorn.common.dto.movie.MovieInfoDTO>>)
```

How do I correct this method of supplementing the map?

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: you can't add values to a map with that type. As a rule of thumb, you can read `? extends` as "read-only", so your map is a map of "read-only" `MovieInfoDTO` objects.

Longer answer: `? extends T` is a bit of a weird type; as you're running up against, the type checker considers different syntactic occurrences expressions with type `? extends T` to be different, incompatible "captures" that don't type check as equal to each other. So since `bElementsToAdd` has type `Map<Long, ? extends MovieInfoDTO>`, then `bElementsToAdd.put()` takes a value of a new "capture" of `? extends MovieInfoDTO`. But there's no way to get that same capture! Even if you did `bElementsToAdd.put(k, bElementsToAdd.get(k))`, the `put` and `get` use different captures so they aren't compatible types!

You clearly don't *want* a read-only map since you're trying to update it. So, you have a few options. One is to remove the wildcard -- that makes sense if you don't care what subtype of `MovieInfoDTO` you've got and you'd be fine with mixing them in the same map. If you *do* care, then you probably meant to add a bound to your overall map:

```
class MyClass<T extends MovieInfoDTO> {
  // ... 
  private final Map<Long, T> bElementsToAdd = new HashMap<>();

  //...
  public Builder withElementsToAdd(@Nullable final Map<Long, T> elementsToAdd) {
   // ...
}
```

This enforces the constraint that the type of elements you add in `withElementsToAdd` must have the same type as the ones in the map, even if you don't care exactly what type that is.

Answer (score 3):

When you place an upper-bound wildcard in your declaration of `bElementsToAdd`, the compiler doesn't know which subtype of `MovieInfoDTO` you have there.  You can theoretically and legally assign a `Map<Long, MovieInfoSubclassDTO>` (`MovieInfoSubclassDTO` being a theoretical subclass of `MovieInfoDTO`) to `bElementsToAdd`.

The method `putAll` is supposed to be able to place all mappings from another map into the original map.  It could have a type as high up as `Map<Long, MovieInfoDTO>`.  The variable `bElementsToAdd` must be able to accept `MovieInfoDTO`s as keys.

Solution: Remove the wildcard upper-bound on `bElementsToAdd`.

```
private final Map<Long, MovieInfoDTO> bElementsToAdd = new HashMap<>();
```

You do not need to remove the upper-bound wildcard on `elementsToAdd` (the parameter to `withElementsToAdd`), and you should not remove it.  Retaining the upper-bound wildcard here allows calling code to pass in a `Map<Long, MovieInfoSubclassDTO>`, which is acceptable because the type `MovieInfoSubclassDTO`, the theoretical subclass of `MovieInfoDTO`, should be allowed as values in `bElementsToAdd`.